# Analysis series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{nx}(x<0)$ convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I try to find this series limit:$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{nx}(x<0)$$
If $x=-1$, there have $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}=\frac{1-1/2^n}{1/2}=2$$

Comment: It is a geometric series and common ratio $2^{x}$ is less than $1$.

Comment: *"When $x\in(-\infty,1),\frac{1}{2^{nx}}>\frac{1}{2^{n}}$, so $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{nx}}$ is converage."* This sentence is wrong in several different ways. 1/ It's $(-\infty,\color{red}{-}1)$. 2/ It's $\frac{1}{2^{nx}}\color{red}{<}\frac{1}{2^n}$, and 3/ the series is *convergent*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=-m$ where $m>0$
So the general term of the series is $a_n=2^{-nm}$
Let's use cauchy $n$th root test
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}2^{-m}=\frac{1}{2^m}<1$$
Hence the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{-nx}$ is absolute convergent